# What can be said about the homotopy groups of $(\widetilde{K}\times X)/G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, fibration, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a simply connected $G$-space. For a $K(G,1)$ space $K$ with universal cover $\widetilde{K}\rightarrow K$ we have that $G$ acts on $\widetilde{K}$ via the unique homotopy lifting property. Then on the product $\widetilde{K}\times X$ we obtain an action by $(g,(k,x))\mapsto (kg^{-1},gx)$.

I aim to express the groups $\pi_n((\widetilde{K}\times X)/G)$ in terms of the groups $G$ and $\pi_n(X)$. To me it seems that such a relation should be obtainable using a suitably chosen fibration and then consider the long exact sequence of that. One of my (failed) attempts was the following: With base space $(\widetilde{K}\times X)/G$, then the projection
$$\widetilde{K}\times X\rightarrow (\widetilde{K}\times X)/G$$
has fibre $X$ and the corresponding long exact sequence turns out as
$$\pi_{n+1}((\widetilde{K}\times X)/G)\rightarrow\pi_n(X)\rightarrow\pi_n(\widetilde{K}\times X)\rightarrow\pi_n((\widetilde{K}\times X)/G)\rightarrow\pi_{n-1}(X)$$
However $\pi_n(\widetilde{K}\times X)\cong\pi_n(X)$ so this particular sequence seems like a dead end.

I have previously shown that $\widetilde{K}\rightarrow K$ is a principle $G$-bundle which actually lead me to the above fibration, but other than that, I can not see what that might be used for.

My question is this: Is my above attempt in fact a dead end? If yes, what fibration could one study to come to desired conclusion, or should I try something other than looking at fibrations?

Comment: What you describe is also called "homotopy orbits", right? I don't know how easy it is to compute the homotopy groups of this, but the homology is called "Borel equivariant homology" and there are techniques to compute this. One could then try to use Hurewicz to find homotopy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the Borel fibration $$X \to EG \times_G X \to BG.$$

Comment: I can see that this fibration yields a very need long exact sequence that allows me to draw the desired conclusion. I have a few follow-up questions now. Is the "Borel fibration" a standard construction? Which assumption makes it a fibration? Is the arrow to the right the one induced by the diagram $BG\leftarrow  EG\times X\rightarrow EG\times_G X$ (the universal property of quotient)? Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose the construction is standard enough; it's used to obtain a spectral sequence for computing the (co)homology of homotopy orbit space.  The second map is given by collapsing $X$ to a point.  To see that it is a fibration, restrict to an open cover $\mathfrak{U}$ of $BG$ for which $EG \to BG$ is trivial.  The Borel fibration becomes $(\mathfrak{U} \times G) \times_G X \cong \mathfrak{U} \times X \to \mathfrak{U}$, which is clearly a fibration, which is enough to conclude that $EG \times_G X \to BG$ is also a fibration.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Can you elaborate why it is _enough_?

Comment: A reference for the fact that fibrations can be checked locally with respect to a numerable open cover, see May's *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*, section 7.4.  (Though be warned of possible typos in proof.)